# SUMIF not working with particular data

Tags: google-sheets

So I am fetching some data using ImportJSON, it's a transaction history search from BSCSCAN, I get the data into my sheet and I want to separate my buys and sells. One column has an output like this...

```
swapETHForExactTokens(uint256 amountOut, address[] path, address to, uint256 deadline)
```

This is a buy using BNB, I want to find all of these, then add up the numbers from another column.

[image: data]

So I want to look through column V find all the buys that used BNB and then add up all the corresponding amounts from column K.

I'm using this...

```
=SUMIF(V2:V21,"swapETHForExactTokens",K2:K21)
```

I have tried many variations, trying different wild cards and such but no luck, it always returns 0, I have tried using SUMIF on another sheet with some basic data that I entered and it works fine, so my only thought is that it doesn't like the data format coming in from the JSON call?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Definitely something to do with the data, I tried this... As you can see, in row 11 I just hardcoded to data, that was seen by SUMIF.

[image]

Comment: This question was bumped by Community user four times.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`=sum(filter(K2:K21, regexmatch(V2:V21, "swapETHForExactTokens")))`

OR

`=sumif(V2:V21,"*swapETHForExactTokens*",K2:K21)`

The point is that you are trying to match *part of the string*, hence `regexmatch` or the wildcard asterisks in the `sumif`.